# Why is there no new table in cnosdb? the data does not seem to be stored in cnosdb

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitor, prometheus-node-exporter, cnosdb

I have configured remote read and write in prometheus, and also configured capture job. Now the data is also displayed on grafana. Why is there no new table in cnosdb? , the data does not seem to be stored in cnosdb.I am using cnosdb official image version 2.0.1

I hope that the monitoring data is stored in cnosdb, and the monitoring data can be displayed in grafana

Answer (score 0):

I checked prometheus later, and there is a lot of data stored here. Data from our monitoring system is stored here. When the remote write fails, promethues will store the data in its own system.